# Trouble with CSS3 transitions

Tags: css, css-transitions

I am not quite sure how to use CSS3 transitions to do what I want.  I'm new to using them so I could really use some help :)

Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zrp8p/3/) with what I'm working on.

So, basically the `div.portlet` is supposed to be a window showing what is in the explode.  WHen you click on the `portlet`, I want it to grow to fill up the `div.containe`r.  And when you close I want it to shrink back to its normal size.

Comment: Hello is my answer solving your question ? or helpful for you ?

Answer (score 0):

fade isnt transact property either you need to definde like `fadeIn` defined below  you can do this by

as in your comment

try

```
div.portlet
{
transition: ease-out 2s;
-moz-transition: ease-out 2s; /* Firefox 4 */
-webkit-transition: ease-out 2s; /* Safari and Chrome */
-o-transition: ease-out 2s; /* Opera */
}
```

and add z-index:3; to `div.portlet` and z-index:4 to class `open`

and jquery

```
$(".container").on("click", ".portlet", function(){
    $(".portlet").css("z-index","3");   
    $(this).addClass("open");    
    $(this).css("z-index","333");    
}); 


});
```

Comment: I've never used keyframes... I'll have to read up more about that.  If I use opacity, isn't that fading?  I'm looking for the div to grow into the full size.

Comment: yeah that's what I mean...how do you add that to the beginning to make it grow too?

Comment: @Syren just added `div.portlet
{ 
transition: ease-out 2s;
-moz-transition: ease-out 2s; /* Firefox 4 */
-webkit-transition: ease-out 2s; /* Safari and Chrome */
-o-transition: ease-out 2s; /* Opera */
}`

Comment: one problem:  I want the text to stay where it is.  The action is good, but the text moves when you close it.

Comment: @Syren you can set this by z-index

Comment: it still doesn't use transition when it's opening.  and the text is still moving.

Comment: @Syren before we got flagged .. should move to chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20546/actionscript

Comment: @Syren there were little mistake was  in fiddle now its working fine http://jsfiddle.net/swamimayank/QszNe/

Comment: still looks the same.  i think i got it here http://jsfiddle.net/Zrp8p/4/  just need to fix the bottom row

Comment: @Syren have you checked last fiddle posted by me comment ??? its works fine ... rather perfect ...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20738/discussion-between-syren-and-nullpointer)